# Obstruction to the existence of constant-rank sections of $T^*M\odot T^*M$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

If $\alpha$ is a section of $T^*M\odot T^*M$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold, the rank of $\alpha$ at $m\in M$ is the codimension of the kernel of $\alpha_m$, i.e. the subspace of vectors $v_m\in T_mM$ that satisfy

$$\alpha(v_m,w_m)=0$$

for all $w_m\in T_mM$.

Given an integer $0\leq r\leq\dim(M)$, is there ever an obstruction to the existence of global constant-rank sections of $T^*M\odot T^*M$? The answer is ``no" when $r=0$ (obviously) or $r=\dim(M)$ (because we can put a Riemannian metric on $M$).

Comment: Sorry if this is an inane question -- what's the definition of $\odot$?

Comment: @Neal It stands for the symmetric tensor product of vector bundles. So a section $\alpha$ of $T^*M\odot T^*M$ is a section of $T^*M\otimes T^*M$ that satisfies $\alpha(w,v)=\alpha(v,w)$ for all vector fields $v,w$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My initial reaction is that the existence of such a tensor field is equivalent (by the usual partition of unity game) to having a distinguished subbundle $E\subset TM$ of rank $n-r$. (And, with a metric, of course, we can take $E^\perp$ and get a splitting of $TM$.) Equivalently, we get an embedding of $M$ into $G(n-r,TM)$, for what it's worth. Perhaps more is true?

Comment: Is $G(n-r,TM)$ the Grassmannian? I see what you mean with your first statement, though. If we have a subbundle $E$, we can even choose $\alpha$ to be positive semi-definite (I think). Is there any reason that there wouldn't be subbundles of $TM$ with any given rank?

Comment: @Josh: In order to have a subbundle of rank $1$, you need a nowhere vanishing vector field (hence Euler characteristic $0$).

Comment: To look for an obstruction to the existence of a rank $k$ subbundle, one should be able to play the standard obstruction theory game by triangulating the base, choosing planes in the tangent bundle over the 1-skeleton, then trying to extend over the higher skeleta, yes?

Comment: @Neal, but there's no reason (I think) that the subbundle has to be trivial.